# Farsi letter 'L' (lam) bugging out with e-diacritic

Tags: babel, arabic

I'm making a document for flash card practice for Farsi. In this document, I include the diacritics with all the Persian words for studying, and I add them using this website:
https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/persian.htm

This works for all the words and diacritics, except for when I have L+e (like so لِ). It instead displays the wrong L (the connected form) in the compiled document.

This only appears with L+e. Adding any other diacritic does not make this happen. Is it a bug, and if so, how can I fix it?

Here's my code. If you look at e.g. "هالِ شُما چِطور اسَت" or "اَهلِ کُجا" it does not show the right L.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[arabic,farsi,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
     \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
     \TOCLanguage{farsi}

\title{Lesson 1 Persian}

\date{\today}
\author{}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle


\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Good day                         &\FR{ روزبه خِیر            }\\[10pt]
Hello                            &\FR{ سَلام                 }\\[10pt]
Good morning                     &\FR{ صبح به خِیر           }\\[10pt]
Good afternoon                   &\FR{ عَصر به خِیر          }\\[10pt]
Good bye (Persian)               &\FR{ خُدا نِگَهدار         }\\[10pt]
Good bye (Formal)                &\FR{ خُداحافِظ             }\\[10pt]
Good bye (Informal)              &\FR{خُدافِظ     }\\[10pt]
Say hello (Plural)               &\FR{ سَلام بِرِسانید       }\\[10pt]
Say hello (Formal                &\FR{ سَلام بِرِسونید       }\\[10pt]
For now                          &\FR{فِعلاً   }\\[10pt]
Thanks (Persian)                 &\FR{ مُتشَکِّرَم           }\\[10pt]
Thanks (Formal)                  &\FR{ مَمنون                }\\[10pt]
Thanks (Informal)                &\FR{ مِرسی                 }\\[10pt]
Yes (Informal)                   &\FR{ آره                   }\\[10pt]
Yes                              &\FR{ بَله                  }\\[10pt]
Positive response to a request   &\FR{ چَشم                  }\\[10pt]
Definitely                       &\FR{ حَتماً                }\\[10pt]
No                               &\FR{ نَه                   }\\[10pt]
How are you? (sgl. you)          &\FR{ چِطوری؟               }\\[10pt]
How are you? (Plural \& Formal)  &\FR{ چِطورید؟              }\\[10pt]
How are you? (Plural \& informal)&\FR{چِطورین              }\\[10pt]
How are you? (How is your state? - spoken)  & \FR{حالِ شُما چِطوره} \\[10pt]
How are you? (How is your state? - written)  & \FR{حالِ شُما چِطور اَست}\\[10pt]
I am well                        &\FR{ خوبَم                 }\\[10pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
I am not bad                     &\FR{ بَد نیستَم            }\\[10pt]
Are you well?                    &\FR{ خوبی؟                 }\\[10pt]
Are you well? (Plural \& Formal) &\FR{ خوبید؟                }\\[10pt]
Delicious                        &\FR{ خوشمَزه               }\\[10pt]
Smart                            &\FR{ زِرَنگ                }\\[10pt]
Beautiful                        &\FR{ زیبا                  }\\[10pt]
Quiet                            &\FR{ ساکِت                 }\\[10pt]
Beautiful/Pretty                 &\FR{ قَشَنگ                }\\[10pt]
Strong (physical)                &\FR{ قَوی                  }\\[10pt]
Small                            &\FR{ کوچَک                 }\\[10pt]
Married                          &\FR{ مُتِاَهِّل            }\\[10pt]
Single                           &\FR{ مُجَرَد               }\\[10pt]
Kind                             &\FR{ مِهرَبان              }\\[10pt]
Middle aged                      &\FR{ میانسال               }\\[10pt]
Upset/Sad                        &\FR{ ناراحَت               }\\[10pt]
Polite                           &\FR{ با اَدَب              }\\[10pt]
Intelligent                      &\FR{ باهوش                 }\\[10pt]
Bad                              &\FR{ بَد                   }\\[10pt]
Big                              &\FR{ بُزُرگ                }\\[10pt]
Impolite                         &\FR{ بی اَدَب              }\\[10pt]
Old                              &\FR{ پیر                   }\\[10pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Lazy                             &\FR{ تَنبَل                }\\[10pt]
Young                            &\FR{ جَوان                 }\\[10pt]
Tired                            &\FR{ خَسته                 }\\[10pt]
Good/fine                        &\FR{ خوب                   }\\[10pt]
Happy                            &\FR{خوشحال}           \\[10pt]
Beautiful/Pretty                 &\FR{ خوشگِل                }\\[10pt]
German                           &\FR{ آلمانی                }\\[10pt]
American                         &\FR{ آمریکایی              }\\[10pt]
Afghan                           &\FR{ افغانی                }\\[10pt]
English                          &\FR{ اِنگِلیسی             }\\[10pt]
Iranian                          &\FR{ ایرانی                }\\[10pt]
Tajik                            &\FR{ تاجیکی                }\\[10pt]
Turkish (Nationality)            &\FR{ تاجیک                 }\\[10pt]
From Tehran                      &\FR{ تِهرانی               }\\[10pt]
Chinese                          &\FR{ چینی                  }\\[10pt]
Japanese                         &\FR{ ژاپُنی                }\\[10pt]
From Shiraz                      &\FR{ شیرازی                }\\[10pt]
French                           &\FR{ فَرانسَوی             }\\[10pt]
Canadian                         &\FR{ کانادایی              }\\[10pt]
Sales person                     &\FR{ فُروشَنده             }\\[10pt]
Worker                           &\FR{ کارگَر                }\\[10pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Employee (office)                &\FR{ کارمَند               }\\[10pt]
Manager/Principal                &\FR{ مُدیر                 }\\[10pt]
Teacher                          &\FR{ مُعَلِّم              }\\[10pt]
Secretary                        &\FR{ مُنشی                 }\\[10pt]
Engineer                         &\FR{ مُهَندِس              }\\[10pt]
Painter                          &\FR{ نَقّاش                }\\[10pt]
Writer/Author                    &\FR{ نِویسَنده             }\\[10pt]
Artist                           &\FR{ هُنَرمَند             }\\[10pt]
Professor                        &\FR{ اُستاد                }\\[10pt]
Cook                             &\FR{ آشپَز                 }\\[10pt]
Nurse                            &\FR{پَرَستار}              \\[10pt]
Police officer                   &\FR{ پُلیس                 }\\[10pt]
Singer                           &\FR{ خوانَنده              }\\[10pt]
K-12 student                     &\FR{ دانِش آموز     }\\[10pt]
Doctor                           &\FR{ دُکتُر                }\\[10pt]
Soldier                          &\FR{ سَرباز                }\\[10pt]
Poet                             &\FR{ شاعِر                 }\\[10pt]
Name                             &\FR{ اِسم                  }\\[10pt]
Mr./Sr.                          &\FR{ آقا                   }\\[10pt]
Exercise                         &\FR{ تَمرین                }\\[10pt]
Tehran                           &\FR{ تِهران                }\\[10pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\newpage
\begin{table}[ht]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Mrs./Ms./Lady                    &\FR{ خانُم                 }\\[10pt]
University                       &\FR{ دانِشگاه              }\\[10pt]
Where from                       &\FR{ اَهلِ کُجا            }\\[10pt]
Several                          &\FR{ چَند                  }\\[10pt]
How nice!                        &\FR{ چه خوب!               }\\[10pt]
What is...?                      &\FR{ چیست؟                 }\\[10pt]
A lot/very                       &\FR{ خِیلی                 }\\[10pt]
In/inside/at                     &\FR{ دَر                   }\\[10pt]
How about you?                   &\FR{ شما چِطور؟            }\\[10pt]
For now                          &\FR{ فِعلاً                }\\[10pt]
Where from                       &\FR{ کُجایی                }\\[10pt]
Germany                          &\FR{ آلمان                 }\\[10pt]
America                          &\FR{ آمریکا                }\\[10pt]
Afghanistan                      &\FR{ اَفغانِستان           }\\[10pt]
England                          &\FR{ اِنگلیس               }\\[10pt]
Iran                             &\FR{ ایران                 }\\[10pt]
Tajikistan                       &\FR{ تاجیکِستان            }\\[10pt]
Turkey                           &\FR{ تُرکیه                }\\[10pt]
Tehran                           &\FR{ تهران                 }\\[10pt]
China                            &\FR{ چین                   }\\[10pt]
Japan                            &\FR{ ژاپُن                 }\\[10pt]
Shiraz                           &\FR{ شیراز                 }\\[10pt]
France                           &\FR{ فَرانسه               }\\[10pt]
Canada                           &\FR{ کانادا               }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to write Farsi is to use `XePersian`, as it is highly specialized and has adaptations of many packages.

See this example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar.ttf}

\begin{document}
لِ
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I couldn't quite reproduce your results, but nonetheless, `xepersian` is the way to go for typesetting English/Persian texts.

*I had some circumstances so I had to use filename for my font. It should normally be

```
\settextfont{XB Niloofar.ttf}
```

See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119362/xepersian-xetex-cant-find-fonts/119372#119372) for font selection.